# Upgrade from Sql Server Entreprise to Evaluation edition, it is possible?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having some trouble upgrading from an Entreprise edition of Sql Server 2008 R2 SP2 to an Evaluation of Sql Server 2014 SP1, and I begin to wonder if it is possible? I didn't found anything about it in the supported version and edition upgrade guide : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393(v=sql.120).aspx

It says that you can't migrate from SQL Server 2014 Entreprise to Evaluation, but it says nothing about previous editions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Brent Ozar speaks to this on his site(bottom link). From the matrix linked below (top), it does not look like that's a supported migration path.

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades?view=sql-server-ver15)

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/08/sql-server-edition-change-standard-edition-enterprise-evaluation/

Comment: Indeed, it is not supported ! Thanks